# 1.9 wither skeleton cannot equip armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a skeleton boss in the 1.9 pre version but the command only summons a wither skeleton that does not have any armor. Could you give me a sample command that spawns a wither that wears diamond armor and a diamond sword?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Franks comment is a fair estimation of what we expect in terms of quality, but that does not make this question off topic. It just makes it a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~ 
{
    SkeletonType:1,
    ArmorItems:
    [
        0:{id:diamond_boots},
        1:{id:diamond_leggins},
        2:{id:diamond_chestplate},
        3:{id:diamond_helmet}
    ],
    HandItems:
    [
        0:{id:minecraft:diamond_sword},
        1:{}
    ]
}
```

Just paste this in a command block, and if you want just add an CustomName tag.

Comment: /summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {SkeletonType:1,ArmorItems:[0:{id:diamond_boots},1:{id:diamond_leggins},2:{id:diamond_chestplate},3:{id:diamond_helmet}],HandItems:[0:{id:minecraft:diamond_sword},1:{}]}